# GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED,

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services, google-drive-android-api

I am attempting to integrate Google Drive into my application with little success. Using the code from the Quick Start repository, I get the following error message every time I select a user account for log in:

```
I/DriveDemo: GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{867e070: android.os.BinderProxy@13cdfe9}, message=null}
```

I have followed the directions at the urls below:

1. https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started
2. https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart

and followed the video at:

1. https://youtu.be/RezC1XP6jcs

I have also looked at numerous Stack Overflow questions and answers with no idea what I am doing wrong.

manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lightkeeper54.chuck.drivedemo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Code:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        // Create the API client and bind it to an instance variable.
        // We use this instance as the callback for connection and connection
        // failures.
        // Since no account name is passed, the user is prompted to choose.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
    // Connect the client. Once connected, the camera is launched.
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE:
            // Called after a photo has been taken.
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Store the image data as a bitmap for writing later.
                mBitmapToSave = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR:
            // Called after a file is saved to Drive.
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Image successfully saved.");
                mBitmapToSave = null;
                // Just start the camera again for another photo.
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE),
                        REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        // show the localized error dialog.
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
        return;
    }
    // The failure has a resolution. Resolve it.
    // Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, and an
    // authorization
    // dialog is displayed to the user.
    try {
        result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.i(TAG, "API client connected.");
    if (mBitmapToSave == null) {
        // This activity has no UI of its own. Just start the camera.
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE),
                REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
        return;
    }
    saveFileToDrive();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
}
```

Comment: Do you register your development/ release key in Google API console?

Comment: All steps to create and register the key were followed.

Comment: @lightkeeper make AuthKey in developer console using yourpackage and SHA key and you are good to go...

Comment: Do keep in mind that Studio's  Instant Run does NOT create a signed APK ... unless you've placed signing information within your app's build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation - [**`SIGN_IN_REQUIRED`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#SIGN_IN_REQUIRED)

> The client attempted to connect to the service but the user is not signed in. The client may choose to continue without using the API. Alternately, if [**`hasResolution()`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#hasResolution()) returns true the client may call [**`startResolutionForResult(Activity, int)`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#startResolutionForResult(android.app.Activity,%20int)) to prompt the user to sign in. After the sign in activity returns with [**`RESULT_OK`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK) further attempts should succeed.

You may also check @Cheok's question, a SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41562702/5995040) that suggested to properly add your SHA-1 and Package Name as asked and enable API once project credentials are all set.

Hope this information helps.

Comment: I followed all steps to create the key and register it in the API console. The API is displaying as active in the console. This is why I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which got fixed after I ensured that every APK build was signed by the same keystore that I used when doing "Get an Android certificate and register your application" as described [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started#get_an_android_certificate_and_register_your_application)

When using Studio, I carried out "automatic signing" by following the steps described in "Configure the build process to automatically sign your APK" as described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#sign-auto). Obviously, use the same keystore as the one used when registering your app (above).